# Handle exception in python program-wide without try-except block

Tags: python, error-handling

There is a way to declare a sort of "global handler" that can catch Exceptions (custom and default one) in any place of the code? Like a general handler that make some operation if a certain kind of exception is raised without the need to use the try-except block where the error can occur.

Thanks for the help!

Edit:
I need a system especially for custom Exception class like for example

```
class InputError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message, errors):

        super().__init__(message)

        self.errors = errors
```

Comment: Any kind of global handler will not be able to access local variables or continue execution, so the best you can do is put the entry point into some kind of "main" function that exists solely to wrap it in a huge try-except. That wiol only be useful if you raise some customized exceptions, otherwise its same as default handling.

Comment: it's exactly what I'm trying to avoid... the use of try-except block _anywhere_

Answer (score 0):

Try using python's decorator 
can refer this https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/professional-error-handling-with-python--cms-25950

Comment: it isn't what I was looking for since: `@log_error, which logs an exception and then re-raises it` so it just give you a log, not a way to handle the error, it will be raised anyway and you will need the try block